# Matrix Representation - Linear Operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I have this question but I seem to be deadlocked in solving it:

Given any basis of the vector space $A = \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$, where the vector space $A$ is the space of all $3\times 3$ matrices.

If $B\in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ is a matrix and also defines a linear mapping:

$ S_B\colon A\rightarrow A$

$ ~~~~~~~\kappa \mapsto B\kappa B^* $

Choose a basis of the vector space A, and find a matrix representation of $S_B$ with respect to the chosen basis.

My approach:

I chose the usual standard basis $E = \{e_1, e_2, \dots e_9\}$ as:

$e_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0\\ 
  0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

$e_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 & 0\\ 
  0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ , etc

Then proceeded to obtain the images of these bases:

$S_B(e_1) = \begin{pmatrix}
  \kappa & 0 & 0\\ 
  0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0\\ 
  0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
  \kappa & 0 & 0\\ 
  0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

Then, $S_B(e_1) = \kappa e_1 + 0e_2 + 0e_3 + \dots + 0e_9 $

This column yields a $9\times 1$ and eventually all the bases would yield $9\times 9$ as a representative matrix. But the linear mapping is an operator since $S_B\colon A \rightarrow A$, which is $3\times 3$. Can anyone help unravel where I am missing it?

Comment: . . what is $B^*$?

Comment: $B^*$ is conjugate transpose.

Comment: oh!, but since you are over the field $\mathbb R$ then conjugating is useless.

Comment: It's a generic notation

Comment: You are confusing $\kappa$ with an entry of a matrix. It is a matrix

Comment: further, linear maps are different to basis' changes

Comment: I suppose a notation for matrices should be consistent in caps, right? The question is actually silent on $\kappa$

Comment: @MaliMali No. Matrices **don't have** to be denoted by large letters. They usually are...but not necessarily. And in this very particular case it happens to be $\;\kappa\;$ is a $\;3\times3\;$ matrix...!

Comment: Thank you for this clarification. I agree with you now since the mapping deals with matrices in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

An operator $\;T\;$ on a linear space $\; V\;$ of dimension $\;n\;$ is represented by an $\;n\times n\;$ matrix. In this case, $\;S_B\;$ is a linear operator on a $\;9\,-$ dimensional space, namely $\;\Bbb R^{3\times3}\;$ and it thus represented by an $\;9\times9\;$ matrix with respect to some given fixed basis of $\;\Bbb R^{3\times3}\;$.

I hope this addresses and solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you for this angle. But do you think my approach is right?

Comment: @MaliMali It can't possibly be since, as already noted in some comment, you're treating $\;\kappa\;$ as if it were a scarlar whereas it is a $\;3\times 3\;$ matrix. Until you don't correct this, your approach cannot be right.